# Create pair virtual com port from c# code without using 3rd party software

Tags: c#, virtual-serial-port

I've searched for a solution, and I've found lots of answers but they all dont satisfied me, I may miss something here.

What I'm doing is a little software that needs to connects to other software with serial port, so I open new com port in my software that the data from the other software is sent to there, and I read from the 2nd virtual comport the data and I do something with it.
all is working perfect, as it was proof of concept.
BUT, I use 3rd party software for virtal comport (pair).

What I need is to create the 2 ports from my software, this software will be sent to few computers and I dont want them to insall any other software besides mine.

I tried to work with the com0com but it seems I need to install it in any PC the software will run on.

does someone have any suggestions?

Comment: That is not going to get you anywhere, a virtual serial port requires a device driver.  Always a separate executable.  You can lose 3 months of your life writing your own but it isn't going to be any better.  Fake hardware tends to be useful in some cases, helps debugging the rest of your code, just mock the serial port like you'd would in a unit test.  And *never* skip testing on the real hardware, virtual serial ports never reproduce the kind of misery that hardware throws at you.  Very unpredictable timing, buffer overruns, framing errors, timeouts are normal and you need to deal with them.

Comment: Thx for the replay I fully agree with you, I may was not clear enough. It isnt for testing purpose. I have an old product I dont want to "Touch" this product knows how to send SMS and I want to add him the abilty to send Mail, so what I did till now is created 2 Pair com ports 1 is assignes in the old software which it sends the data to there, and I listen with my software of the other side and redirect this text to mail. The creation of the pair com port is made with 3rd party software which I like to include in my software, because I will need to send it to end users